# ¿Como puedo centrar la palabra de abajo en HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

sigo haciendo esta pagina y me gustaria saber como podría alinear el Sushi en el centro, para que quede abajo pero exactamente en el centro de Onigiri. Por cuestión de estetica simplemente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es algo asi, que quede el Sushi alineado al centro, y no al costado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 0%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 1.6em;
}

.container {
  width: 85%;
  max-width: 850px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
  padding: 0rem 0;
  font-family: 'Koulen', cursive;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.header a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo-nav-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}

.navigation {
  justify-content: end;
}

.navigation ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
}

.main {
  padding-top: 7rem;
}

.logoimagen {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
}

.sushi {
  display: block;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  animation: banner 10s infinite linear alternate;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

@keyframes banner {
  0%,
  20% {
    background-image: url(./sushi1.jpg);
  }
  25%,
  45% {
    background-image: url(./sushi2.jpg);
  }
  50%,
  70% {
    background-image: url(./sushi3.jpg);
  }
  75%,
  100% {
    background-image: url(./sushi4.jpg);
  }
}

.capa {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  height: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}

.info {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.info h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.info p {
  color: #c8c8c8;
  line-height: 1.7;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.info a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #3088e0;
  padding: 16px 37px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.parrafo1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.parrafo2 {
  margin: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 787px) {
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0rem 1rem;
  }
  .navigation {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
  .navigation ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .navigation ul.show {
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5rem 0rem;
    transition: all 0.4s linear;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .navigation ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Onigiri Sushi</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header class="header">

    <div></div>
    <div class="container logo-nav-container">
      <div class="logoimagen">
        <img class="logo" src="onigiri.png" alt="" width="120px" height="120px">
        <h1 class="">Onigiri Sushi</h1>
      </div>
      <span class="menu-icon">Ver menu</span>
      <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Koulen&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  </header>

  <main class="main">

    <div class="banner">
      <div class="capa">
        <div class="info">
          <h1>¿Tenés antojo de Sushi?</h1>
          <p class="parrafo2">¡Nosotros también, mira nuestro menú y deleitate con nuestra selección de los mejores rolls solo para vos!</p>
          <a href="#">Ver mas</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <p>Página diseñada por Santino Fernandez</p>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ambas páginas contienen texto distinto e imágenes de fondo distintas. No se a lo que te refieres exactamente, si al texto a la imagen. El texto lo veo centrado en ambas tambien, no se ver que queda al costado como dices.

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align:center;
```

Solo debes agregar eso a tu elemento de `h1` y todo el cuerpo del selector se va a centrar

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un `div` que envuelve la imagen y el texto del logo, cuya clase el `logoimagen`. Pues bien, justo a ese `div` le puedes asignar la propiedad `text-align: center;` en el `CSS` y con eso sería suficiente.

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin: 0%;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 1.6em;
}

.container {
  width: 85%;
  max-width: 850px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background: #121212;
  color: white;
  padding: 0rem 0;
  font-family: 'Koulen', cursive;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.header a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo-nav-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}

.navigation {
  justify-content: end;
}

.navigation ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #4a4a4a;
}

.main {
  padding-top: 7rem;
}

.logoimagen {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  /*Justo acá*/
  text-align: center;
}

.sushi {
  display: block;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  animation: banner 10s infinite linear alternate;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

@keyframes banner {
  0%,
  20% {
    background-image: url(./sushi1.jpg);
  }
  25%,
  45% {
    background-image: url(./sushi2.jpg);
  }
  50%,
  70% {
    background-image: url(./sushi3.jpg);
  }
  75%,
  100% {
    background-image: url(./sushi4.jpg);
  }
}

.capa {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  height: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}

.info {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.info h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.info p {
  color: #c8c8c8;
  line-height: 1.7;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.info a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #3088e0;
  padding: 16px 37px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.parrafo1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.parrafo2 {
  margin: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 787px) {
  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0rem 1rem;
  }
  .navigation {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
  .navigation ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .navigation ul.show {
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  .navigation ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5rem 0rem;
    transition: all 0.4s linear;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .navigation ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Onigiri Sushi</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container logo-nav-container">
      <div class="logoimagen">
        <img class="logo" src="onigiri.png" alt="" width="120px" height="120px">
        <h2>Onigiri Sushi</h2>
      </div>
      <span class="menu-icon">Ver menu</span>
      <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Koulen&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="capa">
        <div class="info">
          <h1>¿Tenés antojo de Sushi?</h1>
          <p class="parrafo2">¡Nosotros también, mira nuestro menú y deleitate con nuestra selección de los mejores rolls solo para vos!</p>
          <a href="#">Ver mas</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <p>Página diseñada por Santino Fernandez</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Notas:**

- Ten cuidado con el cierre de etiquetas... `<nav>` por ejemplo, no está cerrada en tu código.
- No recominedo el uso de la etiqueta `h1` en el logo ya que está destinada a los títulos en el `body` y sólo debes agregar uno por página. El uso indebido de las etiquetas puede afectar el SEO.